# Jumpbox battery

Tags: battery-chemistry

First time on this site just signed up hopefully I get the answer I'm looking for.

I'm working with a Coleman Powermate emergency jump-start box. The battery that was in it is a rechargeable sealed lead acid battery 12v, 10.0Ah which is dead.

I want to know if I could replace it with a sealed lead calcium battery which I have a new one here.

Specs are:

- Cycle Use:- 14.4-15.0v
- Stand-by Use:- 13.5-13.8v
- Initial Current:- 2.4A max.

[image]

Comment: the replacement should work .... it may have slightly less capacity though .... the connection tabs are different  .... hopefully the new battery has the wider F2 tabs  ........ https://www.batterystuff.com/images/knowledge-base/f1-vs-f2-terminal-tab.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate that information I wasn't sure because I read up and a lot of people were talking about charging the calcium batteries. I have a trickle charger 12v here will that work and also will the output from the cigarette lighter be enough to also charge it that's built in

Answer (score 2):

Lead acid v lead calcium: There is not much difference between these two chemistries either would do.

A bigger concern is the internal design of the battery. Some lead acid batteries have a lot of area of thin plates and are designed to supply a lot of current for a short period of time. The size of the terminals on the original battery suggests that it has this type of construction.

Your replacement battery has smaller terminals suggesting that it is probably a thicker plate deep cycle battery designed to supply moderate currents for a long period of time.

The only way to be sure is to check the specification of any battery you want to use and ensure that it meets your needs for short term current supply. This parameter is known as Cold Cranking Amps or CCA.

Comment: I wonder what the surge  rating of the dead battery was, because the Calcium battery is only rated for 2.4A and Jumpstart suggests more or is a misnomer